# Add text file resources to R.java

Tags: android

I have text files named hierarchy1.txt, hierarchy1.1.txt and heirarchy1.1.1.txt in my android project->res->raw folder. These files have json objects. I m trying to read from these files but these are not getting added in my R.file. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project (`Project -> Clean ..` in eclipse)?

Comment: The resources should be visible in R.raw.* .Try to use the assets folder if you want to use these filenames. You probably see only R.raw.hierarchy1 right now. If you want to use them under the raw folder, you should use only character that are allowed for variables. For ex. rename your files like hierarchy1_1.txt and heirarchy1_1_1.txt

Comment: cleaning the project did not help. there were compile errors.

Comment: @mihail .. yeah. R.java does not accept file names like a.1.1.txt . when added like this it takes only a.txt . so your naming style is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use underscores instead of dots in your filenames.
If you rename your file to hierarchy1_1.txt you should be able to access it with:

```
context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hierarchy1_1);
```